# How to get Mini-Profiler webpage for Services only

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a ServiceStack API for which I would like to see some profiling data. I do not have any pages (MVC or native) inside the Web Project. How can I view the profiling data?

Answer (score 2):

When you load a `ServiceStack` endpoint from the browser you are presented with an HTML view of that data.  if you have activated MiniProfiler, it will be displayed in the top right of the page.

Please see here for instructions: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling

Comment: I do not allow to have the service to be available via a webpage. So I basically did not configure any endpoint... Maybe it is better to log everything into a database?